# write a program in c using recursion with no loops to get the desired output

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

Rewrite the bubble sort using the recursion method (i.e. no loops), and a print array function that prints out the array before and after the recursive sort is run. The array is:

int ary[] = { 19, 62, 45, 9, 4, 99, 82, 34, 59, 102 }

Write a function that reads the command line arguments and processes two switches: "-min" and    "-max".  If "-min" is selected, the array is sorted from min to max.  If "-max" is selected, the array is sorted from max to min.

Produce your output from the windows cmd prompt using the Release version of your program called rsort.exe.  If no argument is provided on the command line, print out a help message, similar to the following:

USAGE: c:> rsort.exe  WHERE -min [min to max], or -max [max to min

<sup>*Code from comment.*</sup>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ary[] = { 19, 62, 45, 9, 4, 99, 82, 34, 59, 102 };
    int find_max(int *array,int max,int i);
    if (i>=0)
    {
        if (array[i]>array[max])
        {
            find_min(array,i,i-1);
        }
        find_min(array,max,i-1);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: im stuck and my output is confusing me

Comment: This program needs to be in c language not c++ Thanks

Comment: You should include the code in the question, where it can be formatted, rather than in comments where it can't.  I've done it for you this time; please do it yourself in future.  And now clean up the comments.  The C tag says you want C and not C++.

Comment: You should not declare functions inside other functions (much less define them — probably not a problem here, but GCC allows it by default and people sometimes get caught).  You don't show the definition of `find_max()`.  You don't show the declaration of `i`, or `array`, or `max`.  In fact, it looks as though you've tried to nest the definition of `find_max()` inside `main()`, but you used a `;` at the end of the declaration (so it is a declaration) rather than a `{` which would make it a nested defintion — bad, bad, bad!

Comment: You'll need to look at how `max` is assigned new values within the function (at the moment, it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

Will post a fast and sloppy recursive bubble sort I just made.
`find_max` makes an ascending sort. If you want a descending sort, you just make a switch on the lower val instead of the bigger.

For every time find_max is called I print `spos` just to give you a hint on how the work looks like.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int find_max(int [], size_t, int, int);

int main(void)
{
  int ary[] = { 19, 62, 45, 9, 4, 99, 82, 34, 59, 102};

  find_max(ary, sizeof(ary)/sizeof(int), 0, 0);

  for(int i=0; i<sizeof(ary)/sizeof(int); i++)
    {
      printf("%d \n", ary[i]);
    }
  return 0;
}

int find_max(int numbers[], size_t len, int spos, int recurs)
{

  int temp_len = len - recurs;

  if(numbers[spos]>numbers[spos+1])
    {
      numbers[spos]^=numbers[spos+1];
      numbers[spos+1]^=numbers[spos];
      numbers[spos]^=numbers[spos+1];
    }

  printf("%d position \n", spos);

  if(recurs == (len-2))
    {
      return 0;
    }

  if(spos == (temp_len-2))
    {
      find_max(numbers, len, 0, recurs+1);
    }
  else
    {
      find_max(numbers, len, spos+1, recurs);
    }
}
```